# Euclidean distance for each row in dataset

Tags: r

Suppose we have dataset `G2`:

```
data(iris)
G2 <- iris[1:5, -5]
```

We need to calculate Euclidean distance between `x` (row in `G2`) and `G2` (excluding x) for all `x`'s in `G2`, formally

[image]

I wonder what is the best way to to this. Here is my initial attempt:

```
D <- dist(G2)
m1 <- as.matrix(D)
(1 / (5 - 1)) * colSums(m1)
```

Comment: maybe use `dist(G2,diag=T,upper=T)` to fill all the distances in?

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is a bit confusing because you use D differently in the code and formula.  How about

```
m <- as.matrix(dist(G2, upper=T))
D <- apply(m, 2, mean)
n <- length(D)
D <- n/(n-1)*D
```